# How to run a php file without refreshing the web page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem. It is my full honor if anyone helps.

First, let me explain the workflow I want. My CMS is Wordpress. I have a webpage (views.php). In this page, I want to show a download button (id=” download-button”) just to users who has the role subscriber. In default, no one has the role subscriber. So, the button is hidden in default. When a user buys a specific product he gains the role subscriber. Now, suppose a user has opened views.php page as a tab in his browser. In this step, the button is hidden. After that, he opens another tab and buys that specific product and he gains the role subscriber. Now, if he refresh the view.php page, the download button is seen. But, I want the user to see the download button without refreshing the page. In this regard, I wrote button.php file to be called in ajax. However, it does not work.

My codes:
html code (written in view.php which is the place of download button):

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
```

my javascript code (which is put inside view.php file):

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").load("button.php");
  });
});
</script>
```

my button.php code:

```js
<?php
if (check_user_role(array('subscriber'))) {
echo ('<button id="download-button">Download</button>');                        
}               
?>
```

I should note that I have written check_user_role php function in views.php.
It would be my honor if you help.

Thanks in advance.
Milad

Answer (score 1):

As stated by smartdroid in one of the answers above, you can subscribe an event listener function to the window.onfocus event. Try following:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    window.onfocus = function () {
        $("#div1").load("button.php"); 
    }
});
```

I highly recomment you to read further into javascript events.
For plain javascript:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp
For jQuery:
https://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Comment: To explain the code:
The "DOMContentLoaded" event is triggered after body content is ready. This triggers the function with the "event" parameter. This function then creates another listener to the "onFocus" event which is triggered every time a user enters the browser tab, loading the content that `button.php` returns into the div.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you have to use Window setInterval() Method, what this method does it will fire in background at your time interval set.

You can call your ajax code to set/show your button

```
 setInterval(function(){ 
   $("#div1").load("button.php"); 
 }, 3000);
```

Make sure once you do add this button put return false so it wont execute again and again not to increase load on webpage.

Comment: Thanks very much for your comment. I did not work in fact. when I write a simple javascript code it works. but when I include jquery it does not work. As you said I changed my js code but nothing happens. What can I do my friend?

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready event runs only **once** after the DOM is loaded. So this event will not fire unless page is reloaded.

If the user is buying a subscription in another browser tab and then returns to the original tab, windows.onfocus event will fire.

So you can use window.onfocus event to check for subscription every time view.php tab becomes active, and then show the button when necessary. So you can use something like the following, in your view.php

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  window.onfocus = function () {
        $("#div1").load("button.php"); 
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks my friend. Can you pleaes guide me a little more? is there any ways to do what I want without jquery? for e.g. using php javascript mysql etc.Thanks

Comment: window.onfocus event works in vanilla js without jQuery.

Comment: Thanks. But I do not understand the concept. How can I use onfocus event to reach my goal?

Comment: I have provided more clarity in the answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Add an iframe to your view.php that doesn't need to contain anyting nor be visible.

```
<iframe name="download" id="if_download" src="blank.html"></iframe>
```

Target the download-action to the iframe. With some JS:

```
function download(href) {
  window.frames['download'].location = 'download.php?file=' + href;
  return false;
}
```

You may need to wrap the download-action through a php-file to modify its header

**download.php:**

```
$file_name = $_GET['file'];
//validate file exists and *remove any ../ - simple:
if (strpos($file_name, '/') !== false) die('yeah right..');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"$file_name\"");
echo file_get_contents($file_name);
die();
```

Comment: Thanks my friend. You mean: the file will be instantly downloaded after user gains role subscriber? Would you please explain a little more?

Comment: Added some examples, hope it helps.. ;) As i understand, gaining subscriber-access is one action (one roundtrip to the server). Once a subscriber, the button is visible, right? Then when clicking the button, the file gets downloaded without page refresh.

Comment: `?file=../../../../etc/passwd` not ideal, die is superflourious but fitting

Comment: @LawrenceCherone - you're perfectly right, that's obvious but needs to be said.